# Kubuntu boots to black screen and no cursor after installing updates 1/15/14

Tags: kubuntu

On January 6 I installed a daily build of Kubuntu 14.04. Ran great until 1/14/14 after installing updates I booted to a black screen no cursor. I shut down the computer and restarted to a boot menu and booted into recovery mode and chose the latest kernel and ran whatever fixes I was allowed to run. That got me booting normally to the desktop but as soon as I rebooted again I got a black screen no cursor.

So I started fresh today 1/15/14 and immediately ran all updates through the Muon Package Manager and after the updates had completely installed once again booted to a black screen no cursor. So I again booted into recovery mode and was able to boot to desktop. After immediately rebooting I once again got a black screen no cursor. So it must be an update that is preventing booting normally.

If anyone is able to assist I would be very appreciative. Thank you.